# Class Diagram or Object Diagram for Zend framework Gdata

Tags: php, zend-framework, gdata, class-diagram, object-diagram

I am looking for a Class Diagram for Zend Gdata. [Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_SpreadsheetEntry  object](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.spreadsheets.html)

I would like to know if there is a Class Diagram or is it called an Object Diagram, for this is.

Comment: After spending more time learning php I discovered that all I needed to do was use <pre> tags so the print_r gave me a formatted display in my browser.

?><pre><?
print_r($object_to_display);
?></pre><?

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't find a diagram, you could try generating one using one of the following tools:

- [Autodia](http://www.aarontrevena.co.uk/opensource/autodia/)
- [php2xmi](http://tech.motion-twin.com/php_php2xmi.html)

Comment: Nice Idea, just trying to work out how to use those tools, I have windows. php2xmi looks the easiest but still it confuses me. Might have to build a Linux virtual machine.